# Most viewed product

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time, group-by

I am trying to find most viewed product as per user ID. If two products have been viewed for the same number of times then the most recent viewed product is to be selected.

I have the following coding:

```
#tabulating most viewed product by an user in the last 15 days
df_most_viewed_product= new_df.groupby('UserID')['ProductID'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```

Its finding the most viewed product for all the USER IDs except for those, where the USER has viewed two products for the same number of time.In such a scenario I need to get the output as the most recently viewed product.

```
        ProductID   UserID  Activity    OS      date        time
392281  Pr102405    U100040 PAGELOAD    Windows 2018-05-21  04:18:05.465000
764999  Pr102405    U100040 CLICK   Windows 2018-05-23  15:52:02.061000
1501633 Pr105055    U100040 PAGELOAD    Windows 2018-05-23  15:52:39.035000
1603959 Pr100283    U100040 PAGELOAD    Windows 2018-05-25  15:27:37.062000
2212636 Pr100513    U100040 PAGELOAD    Windows 2018-05-27  02:18:47.676000
3093767 Pr100513    U100040 PAGELOAD    Windows 2018-05-26  20:47:49.788000
```

The answer should be Pr100513 as it has been been viewed recently.

Answer (score 0):

Systematically build it up as you describe

- get hits and last hit per **UserID** and **ProductID**
- select rows from this aggregated data frame that match max **hits** and max **last_hit**

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(''' ProductID UserID Activity OS date time 
392281 Pr102405 U100040 PAGELOAD Windows 2018-05-21 04:18:05.465000 
764999 Pr102405 U100040 CLICK Windows 2018-05-23 15:52:02.061000 
1501633 Pr105055 U100040 PAGELOAD Windows 2018-05-23 15:52:39.035000 
1603959 Pr100283 U100040 PAGELOAD Windows 2018-05-25 15:27:37.062000 
2212636 Pr100513 U100040 PAGELOAD Windows 2018-05-27 02:18:47.676000 
3093767 Pr100513 U100040 PAGELOAD Windows 2018-05-26 20:47:49.788000 '''), sep="\s", engine="python")

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"] + " " + df["time"])

# count hits per user and product after sorting so last_hit works
dfh = df.sort_values(["UserID","date"]).groupby(["UserID","ProductID"]).agg(hits=("OS","size"),last_hit=("date","last"))
# select the row with max hits and last hit
dfh.loc[dfh["hits"].eq(dfh["hits"].max()) & dfh["last_hit"].eq(dfh["last_hit"].max())]
```

#### output

```
                   hits                last_hit
UserID  ProductID                              
U100040 Pr100513      2 2018-05-27 02:18:47.676
```